# Обособление одиночного деепричастия

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли обособлять одиночное деепричастие в предложении:*из прикрытия выбрались (,) озираясь(,) парень и девушка*. Возникли сомнения. Запятую ставить не хочется. Вроде бы это и смысловой центр высказывания и обстоятельство образа действия. Выбрались с опасением, осторожно. Правильно ли? Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здесь действительно нужно обособление. Но мотивация более веская, чем предлагается. Ваши же сомнения понятны. Почему понятны, постараюсь раскрыть.

Для начала. Правило звучит не так, что если нельзя заменить на наречие, то  одиночное деепричастие обособляется. Важно, что деепричастие имеет некое наречное значение, а возможность замены на наречие - только признак, не абсолютный.

Наречное значение здесь есть, очевидно. Тем не менее, этого недостаточно. Важно чтобы действие деепричастия характеризовало сам глагол, а не просто обстановку, контекст. И тут мы имеем очевидное противоречие. Глагол у нас совершенного вида, наречие несовершенного. То есть налицо именно то, что Матвей Дёмин назвал "двумя разными действиями".

Вот если бы было "выбирались озираясь" или "выбрались озиравшись" (последняя форма ненормативна, просто для примера), то необходимость обособления была бы не столь очевидна.

А вообще такие вещи часто отдаются на усмотрение автора. Точнее говоря, на то, насколько тесной видит автор связь глагола и деепричастия, рассматривает ли деепричастие как характеристику действия, описываемого глаголом.

Answer (score 3):

По-моему, в данном случае одиночное деепричастие нужно обособить.

**Обособление или необособление деепричастия может зависеть от значения глагола-сказуемого (необособленное деепричастие можно заменить наречием).
Например:  Шел не останавливаясь (шел безостановочно); Спросил, не останавливаясь (деепричастие обозначает второе действие  – спросил, но не остановился для этого).**

В предложении "*Из прикрытия выбрались, озираясь, парень и девушка.*" деепричастие *озираясь* обозначает второе действие.

Answer (score 1):

Да, деепричастие **обособляется:** как уже сказано, оно обозначает **второе действие.**

Автор **так строит структуру предложения**, что в данной позиции  (между подлежащим и сказуемым) деепричастие **удобно обособить** (выбрались и при этом озирались).

Сравнить: Из прикрытия они **вышли озираясь**, прислушивались к каждому звуку.

**Дополнение** (ответы на некоторые общие вопросы)

1) **Можно ли для поверки заменить деепричастие наречием?**  Попробуем  сделать это в нашем примере:  Из прикрытия выбрались  незаметно парень и девушка. Наречие не обособляется, но структура предложения **кажется странной**, инверсия тут явно ни к чему. Правильно сказать: Из прикрытия незаметно выбрались  парень и девушка.

И вывод: необособленное обстоятельство здесь не на месте, поэтому его нужно обособлять.

2) **Можно ли ориентироваться на вид глагола?** Тоже нельзя. В большинстве случаев в роли обстоятельства действия выступают  деепричастия несовершенного вида, но и для деепричастий совершенного вида  это тоже не запрещено: Он шел задумавшись.

3) **Может ли автор принимать решение по своему усмотрению?**

В некоторых случаях структура предложения допускает оба варианта, и тогда мы говорим об авторском выборе, но это не совсем точно. Хотя в приведенном примере верно только одно решение с обособлением, но такое решение тоже выбрал  сам автор, **построив** предложение таким образом, что деепричастие в данной позиции **должно обособляться**.

Comment: Sibylla, Вы написали "Да, деепричастие не обособляется." Так обособляется оно в данном предложении или не обособляется?

Comment: Да, спасибо,  обособляется, конечно, ответ исправлен.